# help with show/hide jquery script

Tags: jquery

I need a js script show / hide with only shown one div at time others closed. By default any (only one) must be shown.

I have got this script: http://jsfiddle.net/kolxoznik1/BFV9k/.

I want to add some class like `show`:

```
 <div class="toggle show">Content</div>
```

If `show` will be added div will not be hided, he will heve status `show()` othervise all divs will be `hide()`.

Suppose someone will help me with my small problem.

Comment: the method you got right now is correct, if you hide the divs what are you gonna click on to show? 0_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the last active element shouldn't hide, then try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".toggle").click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
            $('.active').not(this).toggleClass('active').next('.hidden').slideToggle(300);
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");
        }
    }).next(".hidden").hide();
});
```

[**Here is a forked demo of your version**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/8ECtQ/).

Comment: @Viktors Golubevs: I do not understand you buddy. Are you trying to show multiple elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").hide();
$(".show").show();
```